# Best practices for building a command line with different routes in python

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface

I am building a twitter bot and the way I am communicating with it is using Twitter DMs.  I want to have simple commands which have there own hierarchic routes.  For example:

```
Follow
|
|--> Followers
|       |
|       |--> {screen_name}
|          
|
|--> {screen_name} 

User
|
|--> add
|
|--> delete

Hashtags
|
|--> add
|
|--> delete
```

For example usage to follow all of @barackobama followers one would type "Follow Followers barackobama".  What would be the best way to parse it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Best" is very subjective, especially for such a broad subject as parsing. There are multiple ways of handling this, some which might be considered "better" than others, but still no "best". Tell us what you have, and what problems you have with it, and we can help you.

Comment: How about what would be the cleanest implementation which allows me to easily add more commands without hassle.

Comment: Requiring the user to understand your module's internal organization seems counterproductive.  Why not simply have a command `followers`?

Comment: “Best practices” questions are not welcome on Stackoverflow because they give rise to opinion-based answers and also they're too broad. Anyway here's a list of frameworks for writing command-line applications--maybe it helps http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/cli/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases like this, I tend to use regexes with named capture groups.

Example:

```
import re

def follow(name):
    print 'following ' + name 

cmds = {
        'Follow (?P<name>[a-z]+)': follow,
}

a_cmd = 'Follow foobar'
for expr, action in cmds.iteritems():
    # try to match the pattern onto the given command
    m = re.match(expr, a_cmd, re.I)
    if m:
        # if matched, call the corresponding action, using
        # the named groups as keyword arguments.
        action(**m.groupdict())
```

For more fancyness one could replace the simple callback action with a class containing more bells and whistles. In case of doubt, KISS. :-)

Edit: As Some programmer dude points out, this is somewhat of a misuse of a dictionary. (However it makes for a nice concise appearance on the screen). A cleaner solution would be a list of namedtuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Cmd = namedtuple('Cmd', 're action')
cmds = [
    Cmd(re='Follow (?P<name>[a-z]+)', action=follow),
)
# etc.
```

Comment: A dictionary where the key is a regular expression is kind of useless IMO. It doesn't use the mapping part of the dictionary. Might as well have a list of tuples.